# How to modify the legend of my barplot in R?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, legend

In this barplot, the legend is blocking off a portion of it. How can I reduce the size of the legend?

```
My code:

`work.gender.marriage.table = table(work$marriage,work$gender)`
```

[image]

```
`barplot(work.gender.marriage.table,main = "Gender & Marriage",
beside = TRUE,
legend = rownames(work.gender.marriage.table))`
```

My data:

```
`structure(list(marriage = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L),    class = "factor", .Label = c("D", "M", "NM", "W")), gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), val = c(12L, 61L, 78L, 56L, 71L, 33L, 86L, 93L)), .Names = c("marriage", "gender", "val"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")`
```

This is the image after using the code:

```
 barplot(work.gender.marriage.table,main = "Gender & Marriage",
 beside = TRUE)

 legend("topright", 
        legend = rownames(work.gender.marriage.table), 
        ncol = 2,
        cex = 0.5)
```

Image:[image]

Comment: The "enter image description here" is not part of my code; ignore that. It does contain the image of my barplot if you click on it!

Comment: one option is to use par(xpd=TRUE) before legend() so that it appears outside the plotting area.

Comment: Hi ed_sans! Thank you for the advice; I keep getting the following error:

"Error in width/2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(width) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

Would this be because I do not have the appropriate package?

Comment: You should provide a working dataset with your question. Say work.gender.marriage.table

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what to fix in my code; I thought it had a working dataset? Is there a way you can show me within my code what you mean? 

Thank you again!

Comment: If you add the data we can run the codes other wise it's just guessing. Use dput(work.gender.marriage.table) to add your data.frame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
barplot(work.gender.marriage.table,main = "Gender & Marriage",
beside = TRUE)
```

Then add your legend as:

```
legend("topright", 
       legend = rownames(work.gender.marriage.table), 
       ncol = 2,
       cex = 0.5)
```

Based on your data:

```
df = structure(list(marriage = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), class = "factor", .Label = c("D", "M", "NM", "W")), gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), val = c(12L, 61L, 78L, 56L, 71L, 33L, 86L, 93L)), .Names = c("marriage", "gender", "val"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
df


dfM <- df[which(df$gender=="M"),]
dfF <- df[which(df$gender=="F"),]
dfN <- cbind(dfM[,3], dfF[,3])
colnames(dfN) <- c("M", "F")
rownames(dfN) <- dfM$marriage
dfN

barplot(dfN, beside=T, legend.text = rownames(dfN),
        args.legend = list(x = "topleft", bty="n", cex = 0.7, ncol = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: I used "
barplot(work.gender.marriage.table,main = "Gender & Marriage",beside = TRUE,legend = list(rownames(work.gender.marriage.table), (cex = 0.5) "

and I would not get an error, or a change in the image, but "+"s instead of ">"s

I'm sorry for the confusion!

Comment: AK88; I think it was close! I received one error stating:

"Error in barplot.default(work.gender.marriage.table, main = "Gender & Marriage",  : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix"

And the graph had the same legend unmoved, but it did create a smaller legend in the top right corner with the numbers 1-8. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: check this part carefully `legend = rownames(work.gender.marriage.table)`

Comment: You mean like this:

barplot(work.gender.marriage.table,main = "Gender & Marriage",beside = TRUE, legend("topright"), legend = rownames(work.gender.marriage.table), ncol = 2, cex = 0.5)

?

Comment: No, take the `legend` outside. Just copy and paste my code :))

Comment: Almost! everything is perfect, except the numbers 1-8 still appear instead of the marriage information. I'm trying to add some of my dataset to this question but I'm very confused. First day in R is not going well. I'm sorry for taking your time I really appreciate your help!

Comment: No worries at all. Just do this `dput(work.gender.marriage.table)` and copy and paste the output to your question.

Comment: Btw, where are you getting your data from?

Comment: Okay I'll try that! It's from a professor for an assignment! It does not say we need to reduce the size of the legend, but if it weren't an assignment I would definitely have to. Plus R is used in my lab so might as well not do the bare min!

Comment: AK88 I have tried placing the output in my code, but it is not working still sadly. I might be placing it in the wrong area of my code?

Comment: No, you have to paste the `dput()` output here, in the body of your question so that we can see your data.

Comment: Oh I see!

Like this?

structure(list(marriage = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L), class = "factor", .Label = c("D", "M", "NM", "W")), 
    gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", 
    "M"), class = "factor"), val = c(12L, 61L, 78L, 56L, 71L, 
    33L, 86L, 93L)), .Names = c("marriage", "gender", "val"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Yep. Give me a moment.

Comment: AK88; Thank you! I updated my question with the image I received. I am not sure why our graphs differ, but I wrote down the code I used to receive this graph. I may have made a mistake. Thank you!!

Comment: Looks like your legend is still blocking some bars. Try this `barplot(dfN, beside=T, legend.text = rownames(dfN),  args.legend = list(x = "top", bty="n", cex = 0.7, ncol = 2))`

Comment: I see; where do I put this exactly? The areas I am inserting it gives me errors sadly!

Comment: Try this: `barplot(dfN, beside=T, legend.text = rownames(dfN), args.legend = list(x = "top", bty="n", cex = 0.7, ncol = 2))`

Comment: Yes, but where do I place this code? I am not placing it in the correct area.

Comment: You can ignore the previous two `barplot()` and `legend()` codes and just run this code instead.

Comment: I receive the following error:

Error in barplot(dfN, beside = T, legend.text = rownames(dfN), args.legend = list(x = "top",  : 
  object 'dfN' not found

Comment: Maybe I am lacking a package?

Comment: No, you are fine. Just change `dfN` to `work.gender.marriage.table`. Everywhere.

Comment: YESSSS IT WORKS!!! YOU'RE THE BEST!!!! Thank you so much for your patience and all of your help!! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You could use ggplot2 as well.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(work.gender.marriage.table) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = val, x = cat), stat="identity") + facet_grid(. ~ sex)
```

Example data.frame:

```
work.gender.marriage.table <- data.frame(cat = c("D", "M", "NM", "W", "D", "M", "NM", "W"),
                                         sex = rep(c("M","F"), each = 4),
                                         val = sample(1:100,8))
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great! I'm attempting to try this code; sorry i'm completely new to R so I'm getting a grasp of this language.

Comment: Please edit your question adding the output of dput(work.gender.marriage.table), which is your dataset.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with how to do that; as in upload my dataset to this page?

Comment: Yes, edit your question. Put the original dataset or the table with the counts. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example